# Can't import the MongoDB public GPG Key : "Connection timed out"

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04, apt-key, keyserver

I am trying to install mongodb on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I am stuck on the very first step:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 
9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
```

Gives me the following error message:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.s5jlAD8mdG/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4

gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out
```

I have lost a whole day trying to fix it, could someone help me please?

Thanks!